# facebook real time update - comments on page post

Tags: facebook-graph-api, subscriptions, real-time-updates

I have a page that has a working subscription for my application, and real time updates are being sent from facebook to my callback URL.

```
{
      "object": "page",
      "callback_url": "...",
      "fields": [
        "feed"
      ],
      "active": true
    }
```

When some user posts on my page wall, i receive a callback. I answer with my page, and receive a callback. Someone reply back with a comment, callback is received.

When my application(page) posts on the wall of a page, callback comes that a post on a page has been made. 
The problem is when anyone makes a comment on that post, callback never comes. I dont know why, it was a change in a feed of a page.

So the problem is only when a comment is made to a post made by page, can anyone help me understand why ? Or is there some kind of a bug that i am not aware of, or should this be solved somehow different ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have realized what is the problem, and it seems it is something on the side of facebook.

If there is a post on the wall by page that contains status update, or a post that contains image, comments on those posts are always sent back as call-back url, like this.

```
{object:page,entry:[{id:404799186292933,time:1426759193,changes:[{field:feed,value:{item:photo,verb:add,photo_id:693957037377145,post_id:404799186292933_693957097377139,sender_id:404799186292933}}]}]}

{object:page,entry:[{id:404799186292933,time:1426759277,changes:[{field:feed,value:{item:comment,verb:add,comment_id:693957037377145_693957777377071,parent_id:404799186292933_693957097377139,sender_id:100003882169397,created_time:1426759277}}]}]}
```

As we can see here, first post was a post with image by page, it contains item photo, and then there was a comment by random user on that post, and the comment payload was returned.

Here we have a post by page on the wall that contains link, www.google.com for example. Comments made by users on this kind of posts are never returned on call-back url. So there must be something wrong on the side of facebook because i see no reason that posts that contain links should be treated differently then posts that contain only text or image or video.

```
{object:page,entry:[{id:404799186292933,time:1426759293,changes:[{field:feed,value:{item:share,verb:add,share_id:693957890710393,post_id:404799186292933_693957890710393,sender_id:404799186292933}}]}]}
```

EDIT:
I ve reported a bug and they are already aware of it.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1618206345064602/

Seems like it will be fixed by facebook in the future.